# Which of these codes is better, and would you change anything in the code to improve it, to make it better?

Tags: css

Of these 3 CSS codes, which code set up is better to use and why?

All 3 codes are set up differently, but they all accomplish the same thing.

I'm trying to figure out which one I should use.

https://jsfiddle.net/75tu065b/2/

http://testing45435.blogspot.com/

**Code 1**

https://jsfiddle.net/3fcc4cn5/1/

```
.link div {
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
    height: 50px;
  }

 .link div:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
```

**Code 2**

https://jsfiddle.net/x7s124jc/3/

```
  .link div {
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
    font-size: 0;
  }

  .link a:first-child {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }

  .link div:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
```

**Code 3**

https://jsfiddle.net/v4yrd6dq/1/

```
  .link div {
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
  }

  .link div:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  .myLink a {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
```

Comment: `All 3 codes are set up differently, but they all accomplish the same thing.` What is it you're trying to accomplish? This type of question might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, Code 1 is the best. If they all do the same thing, use the shortest one: It means less for the user to download, and your file is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to add rules only if you really need them to avoid unwanted and unexpected behaviours. So,between these options I'd choose **Code 1** because the other options contains extra rules that don't influence visually the behavior of your page.